# UserName from 'Win32_ComputerSystem' of windows machine is always null in remote machine

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am using the method below to get logged in user name in windows(it's being used in windows service). It works well(`MY-Username(Pc-Name)`) on my machine but when I install it to some other windows machine it returns only Name(`(Name)`) value since UserName is null, whats might cause this?

Unfortunately I am not able to install VS in that remote machine, hope still there is way to fix it

```
private string GetUserName()
        {
            string result = "";
            using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT UserName, Name FROM Win32_ComputerSystem"))
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
                {
                    if (mo["UserName"] != null)
                        result = mo["UserName"].ToString();

                    if (mo["Name"] != null)
                        result += " (" + mo["Name"].ToString() + ")";
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Is there a user logged into the remote machine?  I am guessing.. probably not. "Name of a user that is logged on currently.".. your WMI session doesn't count.

Comment: Yes I am, I have installed the service..

Comment: I don't think it works for something running as a service.  Only something logged in that gets a desktop profile.